# How to recover data from bitlocker encrypted ssd without encryption key?

Tags: data-recovery

Some time ago I got a new ssd, after some weeks I decided to encrypt its data with bit locker using the full disk encryption option and encryption key stored in usb device. But now it happened that I lost the usb device, and i don't know my recovery password. Is there a way to recover the data from this drive?

Comment: The whole point of encryption is that without the password or recovery keys then decryption is so near to impossible that it not feasible for anyone to recover the data from it. You could try brute forcing the password, but generally they talk about thousands of millions of years even if you had access to almost all of the computer processing power on the planet. You are unlikely to be able to use brute force and find the correct key within your lifetime using your own home computer.

Comment: @Mokubai - this ought to be the answer.

Comment: There is a standard Industry method of recovering such data. It has been used for decades and works with all encryption methods, past, present, and future. And it maintains security. That is - recover the files from your backups. All files of any importance should have at least 1 backup copy while those of particular importance should have 2 or more backup copies. Encrypted files are no exception, you just need to take appropriate precautions with the backup media.

Comment: @LMiller7 which method is this?

Comment: As I said, copy the files from your backkups. If you do not have such backups, why not?

Comment: Oh now i got it. Unfortunately my last backup doesn't have all the files i need.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no. (That's the whole point of full disk encryption after all).

Answer (score 0):

**NO, THERE IS NO WAY FOR THAT**

This is the primary goal of encryption: prevent access to the content without the key.